# Is it possible to have an Android app dial a remote modem and send info back and forth?

Tags: android

Is it possible for an Android application use the cell phone to dial out to a remote modem and interact with it? I have a PC program that calls to a remote modem and collects data from a controller. The information send back and forth between the PC app and the controller is just a simple string of characters. I would like to port some of this application to work on a cell phone, if possible. Does the Android OS provide for this type of communication? If so, is there some API's that make this work easier?

If the Android OS doesn't provide this ability, is there any other mobile OS that does?

Thanks for any help with this.